# How to set date in quarterly format using toLocaleDateString or toLocaleTime string?

Tags: javascript, locale

How can I convert a date to a string of format `"QQQ ''yy"` (eg: `Q1 '24`) using `toLocaleDateString` or `toLocaleTime`?

I tried to look through the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#options

Comment: I'm afraid that DateTimeFormat options do not support quarters. You might want to determine the quarter manually and concatenate it with the locally formatted date.

Answer (score 1):

A function that will turn `Date` class param to your desired string:

```
const formatQuarterYear = (date) => {

  // Calculate the quarter
  const quarter = Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3) + 1; // +1 because getMonth() starts from 0

  // Get the last two digits of the year
  const year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);

  return `Q${quarter} '${year}`;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do this using toLocaleDate/toLocaleTime string because I want to convert the date to different languages without using a library, so if you have any suggestions kindly let me know.